# Welcome email specific to user role

Tags: user-roles, wp-mail

I would like to send an additional welcome email to a specific user role, 'freelancer'. WP would still send its standard welcome email, with login and password, to all user roles.

I found the following code :

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification', 'my_if_notification_required' );
function my_if_notification_required( $user ) {
    $user = get_userdatabylogin( $user );
    if ( $user && in_array( 'freelancer', $user->roles ) ) return true;
    else return false;
}
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'my_notification_text' );
function my_notification_text( $user, $user_email, $key, $meta ) {
    $user = get_userdatabylogin( $user );
    if ( !$user || !in_array( 'freelancer', $user->roles) ) return false;
    $message = 'Your message';
    return $message;
}
```

Only this does not seem updated. What function should I use?

Comment: what does a `print_r` of your `$user->roles` look like?

Comment: Hello Brandt, iam very new at php! how would I use print_r with the function?

Comment: Sorry Sonia - I wasn't aware. so `print_r($expression)` basically is a version of `var_dump` and what it does is presents to you (via echo) a hierarchical, visual representation of the expression passed to it. The reason I asked is that the $users->roles array may not contain what you expect or it may be not even of array type.  `Roles` have changed a bit in wordpress over the years, and now there is a greater emphasis on the comingling of Roles and Capabilities. 

https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I made some research on print_r, i understand more or less how to add it to code, and that it would display the result on frontend. But with the function above, I dont understand how to implement it and where it should display the results?